# Circuit board defect on harddrive - fixable?

Tags: hard-drive

So, my parents managed to fry their hard-drive microcontroller (somehow, by vacuum cleaning the PC), which now looks kinda like this:

[image]

They asked me if I can do something about it and after reading up on the problem, it said that it is possible to fix this, if only the circuit board is damaged.

We are talking about a Samsung Spinpoint SP1604N by the way, an 160 GB IDE hard-drive.

Anyway, I was searching on ebay for other hard-drives of this type, which have been produced as close as possible to the damaged one. I even got one, that's from the same month. I then proceeded to change the curcuit board, which was fairly easy.

Instead of doing nothing, the drive now spins up, when I power it and then stops after about 4 seconds or so (I have put the drive in an external case to test this).

So my question now is: is there anything else I can do, to get the drive to work? Is it possible I did something wrong on the way, that permanently damaged the drive? The data on it is not really worth the effort of professional recovery, but it would still be nice to get it back. I was also playing around with the pin settings of the drive, but to no avail.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  You have replaced the controller board, I assume, with one that is capatible with your drive.  If it does not work then there is something beyond just the controller board that is not working.

Comment: Since I'm not really experienced with this kind of stuff, I was just wondering if there is something I was overlooking some things, which might help in getting the drive to work. There have also been reported cases, that circuit boards of other drives might not work, even if it is the same type, which can be caused by several reasons (like different firmware or whatever). This question here is like my last shot at trying to find another possible solution to this problem.

Comment: Yes.  The controller board has to be exactly from the same model hdd and firmware otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Is that a static discharge hole in the chip (pic is vague)?

Comment: Those are three small holes, that are burned right through the plastic. I was told that it gave a strong smell of burned plastic. So I'm assuming that this would be a yes.

Comment: It's dead, Jim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, repairing a dead hard-drive by swapping the circuit board rarely works anymore. In the old days when hard-drives had relatively low data-densities, you could swap the circuit board of one with that of an identical (or sometimes even *similar*) model and it would work (I did this with a few 512MB Maxtors back in the day).

The problem is that modern drives have a much higher density with much more, smaller bits packed into the same amount of space. This means that there is much less room for error when it comes to accessing them because everything is so much smaller and closer together. As such, even two drives that are of identical models and even from the same lot could end up with microscopic differences due to varying calibration of the manufacturing equipment (in fact, two drives from the same *lot* could be different since the equipment could slowly skew out of alignment throughout the day in the time between the two were made).

Therefore, the drive controllers are tuned to that specific drive at the factory, and so may very well not work with another seemingly identical drive because it has its tracks and such slightly off. You would need a way of calibrating the replacement board to the old drive’s platters, and I have yet to find a program or anything that is available to consumers which can do that.

Sadly this means that as time goes by, even though storage gets larger and cheaper, it also means that data-recovery becomes more difficult and expensive. On the bright side (sort of), it also means that storage should get cheap enough that most people *should* be able to afford to make backups.

In summary, chances are that you did nothing that specifically killed it, but the board is simply not compatible. What is probably happening is that the controller tries to read the platter, but cannot align correctly and then just shuts down.

<sup>(I had a similar incident a year or two ago. I bought a SATA-to-USB adapter on eBay and managed to move a bunch of files to it. Unfortunately something went wrong and one of the chips burned out—ah that fried electronics smell!—and the drive was toast, literally. I have been looking for a replacement board ever since, but unfortunately even within the same model, there are a bunch of different revisions, so finding an exact duplicate is a huge challenge, and the closest I can find would be some sites that specifically sell replacement boards for drive repair, but those are (way too) expensive and not guaranteed to work. Thankfully this time, the files were not irreplaceable, so while very inconvenient, I *could* get them back some day when I have enough drive to do so—though a simple file listing would have been really great since I don’t know exactly what I lost.)</sup>